# Bijection between two Peano triples.

Tags: functions, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

Let $(P_1, \sigma_1, s_1)$ and  $(P_2, \sigma_2, s_2)$ be two Peano triples. Can we show that there exists a bijection $g:P_1 \to P_2$ such that $g(\sigma_1) = \sigma_2$ and $g \circ s_1 = s_2 \circ g$. If yes, how to prove it?

My answer is no, as cardinality of $P_1$ and $P_2$ may not be same. Is my reasoning correct?

A Peano triple is a triple $(N,1,\sigma)$ where $N$ is a set, $1 \in N$, and $\sigma : N \to N$ is a map such that

1. $\sigma$ is injective;
2. $\sigma(N) = N \setminus \{1\}$;
3. for any subset $S \subset N$ if $1 \in S$ and $\sigma(S) \subset S$ then $S = N$.

Comment: What is a "Peano triple"? (Are you using [this definition](https://books.google.com/books?id=uX36AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%22Peano+triple%22&source=bl&ots=q9VtvRIGKc&sig=4iqN-dyXf_9UE5fhEvk-C1efzwc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipnaqAoLPdAhVN2qwKHbgiBu4Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Peano%20triple%22&f=false)?)

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry not to define it properly.

Comment: Then here's a hint: *can* the cardinalities of $P_1$ and $P_2$ in fact be different?

Comment: yes they can be.

Comment: Are you sure? Why do you think they can be?

Comment: Isn't it $P_1$ and $P_2$ are arbitrary sets?

Comment: No, they're arbitrary sets **which form the domain of some Peano triple**. Not every set is the domain of a Peano triple! For example, is there a Peano triple $(P,\sigma,s)$ where $P$ has seventeen elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've claimed that there are Peano triples of different cardinalities; while this would indeed imply that the statement you're analyzing is false, your claim is not correct. In fact, the statement you're analyzing is **true**: any two Peano triples are isomorphic.

*REMARK (ignore this if you're not familiar with model theory): In light of the existence of [nonstandard models of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) this might seem like a contradiction, but it's not. The existence of nonstandard models relies on the theory in question being [**first order**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), and you're looking at the [**second-order**](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#2) version of Peano arithmetic - the quantifier over all sets (axiom (3)) is not first-order.*

---

Here's a sketch of the proof:

You already know of one Peano triple - namely, $(\mathbb{N},1,succ)$. Now suppose $(P,\sigma,s)$ is another Peano triple; you want to show that $(P,\sigma,s)$ is "the same as" *(in the appropriate sense)* the Peano triple $(\mathbb{N},1,succ)$.

- There is a natural function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow P$ given by "counting" the elements of $P$. For example, $f(1)$ should be $\sigma$, and $f(2)$ should be $s(\sigma)$. Do you see how to define $f$ in general?
- Can you prove that $f$ is in fact an injection?
- Now you would be done with the problem if you could show that $f$ is a **bijection** (why?). So suppose it's not. Let $S=P\setminus range(f)$. Can you show that $S$ has a weird property that means that $(P,\sigma,s)$ is in fact *not* a Peano triple?

*The focus on the specific triple $(\mathbb{N},1,succ)$ above is unnecessary - we could develop a similar argument for showing that two arbitrary Peano triples are isomorphic, directly - but I think the approach above makes things more concrete.*

Comment: Is it true $f(1) = \sigma$ and $f(n) = s(f(n-1))$ for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: @MittalG Yup. (Actually there's a bit more going on than meets the eye - you need to prove that this rule actually defines a unique function! But you can do that using mathematical induction. In fact, a "Peano triple" is **exactly** a structure over which you can do mathematical induction in the usual way - that's exactly what part (3) of the definition says!